# Postfix is not responding on port 465 (SMTPS)

Tags: ssl, postfix, email-server, port, smtps

I have Postfix and I've configured it to listen on port `465` for `SMTPS`.

When I telnet to port 465, it does not respond but it does respond on port 25. I've googled for days and nothing has worked for me so far; so now I am coming for some help. Below are my main.cf and master.cf files for Postfix.

**main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.factorioserverlisting.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.factorioserverlisting.com
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.0.0.0/24
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html

home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_secruity_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

**master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**Any assistance getting Postfix to respond to SMTPS connections on port 465 would be kindly appreciated!**

Comment: Just a comment on your question. "When I use telnet to port 465, it is not finding it." This is a bit hard to understand what it means exactly. A copy-paste from the telnet ocmmand and its output is more clear way to indicate the problem.

Comment: It was clear to me. His postfix installation was not responding on port 465. Please take this off hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do my best to give you some ideas, things to try...

**Perhaps referring to the port numerically rather than by service name will help**

From http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html

```
Service name
              The service name syntax depends on the service type as described
              next.

Service type
              Specify one of the following service types:

              inet   The  service listens on a TCP/IP socket and is accessible
                     via the network.

                     The service name is specified as host:port, denoting  the
                     host   and  port  on  which  new  connections  should  be
                     accepted. The host  part  (and  colon)  may  be  omitted.
                     Either  host  or port may be given in symbolic form (host
                     or service name) or in numeric form (IP address  or  port
                     number).   Host  information may be enclosed inside "[]";
                     this form is necessary only with IPv6 addresses.

                     Examples: a  service  named  127.0.0.1:smtp  or  ::1:smtp
                     receives mail via the loopback interface only; and a ser-
                     vice named 10025 accepts connections on  TCP  port  10025
                     via  all  interfaces  configured with the inet_interfaces
                     parameter.
```

**So create a section like this**

```
465     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

**I added this line to my Postfix server to see what would happen and it worked. Have you tried without all the options?**

```
smtps       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

**You can check what ports Postfix is actually listening on with `lsof` (`urd` is port `465` as defined in `/etc/services`)**

```
$ lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep master
master   10387     root   12u  IPv4 1303420      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
master   10387     root   13u  IPv6 1303421      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
master   10387     root   17u  IPv4 1303426      0t0  TCP *:urd (LISTEN)
master   10387     root   18u  IPv6 1303427      0t0  TCP *:urd (LISTEN)
```

**Checkout this option. It could be causing connections to be rejected.**

```
-o smtpd_client_restrictions
```

From http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

> smtpd_client_restrictions (default: empty) Optional restrictions that
>   the Postfix SMTP server applies in the context of a client connection
>   request. See SMTPD_ACCESS_README, section "Delayed evaluation of SMTP
>   access restriction lists" for a discussion of evaluation context and
>   time.
>
> The default is to allow all connection requests.
>
> Specify a list of restrictions, separated by commas and/or whitespace.
>   Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace.
>   Restrictions are applied in the order as specified; the first
>   restriction that matches wins.

If none of this helps, can you please post your Postfix log from when it starts up?

Comment: Didn't work.. :(

Comment: @Matt sorry to hear that... was still adding stuff to my answer, take a look...

Comment: @Matt Can you telnet to port 25?

Comment: Okay.. removing the options worked.. and yeah, I could telnet to EVERY port but 465.

Comment: However, I can connect to it via telnet, I still can't send or receive emails? MXtoolbox can't connect to my email either. Any ideas off the top of your head to look at? (Port forwarding is setup)

Comment: @Matt How are you trying to send email? What does your mail log say? As for mxtoolbox.com, that would be a firewall/port forwarding issue probably. I can't help you much there. Try a port scanning website for a second opinion. Do you have other things setup with port forwarding that work? Do you have another system out on the internet that you can use to test? There are some free shell account services that might be useful for that purpose - maybe... never tried it.

Comment: I am actually attempting to send it via squrrelmail because I have it configured for that. I have iptables set to allow all incoming and outgoing traffic on those ports.

You can go here: https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap and type in factorioserverlisting.com and test for yourself. Could my MX records just be messed up? I couldn't find a tutorial really explaining them well, but I believe I have it configured correctly.

Comment: @Matt Think about putting new info about Squirrel mail and your network setup into a new question so we can get it all sorted out. Also make sure to do some debugging work on your own, and document it in the new question.