# Postfix smtp vs smtpd -o options

Tags: postfix, openssl

Table below shows which protocols/ports could be used in each step of the email transfer. Table also indicates which protocols/ports I want to use on my `postfix` server setup by marking them with ✘ or ✔.

| n | operation | sender | receiver | possible protocols/ports |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | *"mail submission"* | MUA | MSA | (✘) SMTP `25` (✘) SMTP `25` & `STARTTLS` (✘) SMTP `587` & `STARTTLS` (✔) SMTPS `465` & implicit TLS |
| **2** | *"server internal"* | MSA | MTA | / |
| **3**... | *"mail relay"* | MTA | MTA | (✘) SMTP `25` (✘) SMTP `25` & `STARTTLS` (✔) SMTP `25` & `STARTTLS` & DANE |
| **n -2** | *"server internal"* | MTA | MDA | / |
| **n - 1** | *"server internal"* | MDA | MS | / |
| **n** | *"mailbox access"* | MS | MUA | (✘) POP3 `110` & `STARTTLS` (✘) POP3S `995` & implicit TLS (✘) IMAP `143` & `STARTTLS` (✔) IMAPS `993` & implicit TLS |

Before I continue I would ask you to agree or disagree with two of assumptions:

### ASSUMPTION A:

I assume from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/795295/postfix-is-not-responding-on-port-465-smtps#answer-795297) old answer that Postfix *service* `465` was renamed to `smtps` somewhere along the way. Therefore I am using *service* `smtps` in order to listen on *"mail submission"* SMTPS port `465`.

### ASSUMPTION B:

The top of my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file looks like this:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

  ...
```

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/696936/whats-the-difference-between-postfix-smtp-and-postfix-smtpd#answer-696943) that:

> `postfix/smtpd` - is SMTP daemon process for *"incoming mail"* and routing it to the appropriate internal location.
>
> `postfix/smtp` - is SMTP daemon process for *"outgoing mail"* out to the world.

So now I am assuming that `postfix/smtpd` is listening on port `465` for *"incoming email"* from local users and on port `25` for *"incomming email"* from everywhere else. I am also asumming that `postfix/smtp` is using port `25` where it sends *"outgoing email"*.

### PROBLEM:

When I was configuring Postfix somewhere along the way I disabled an entire TLS section inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf` because I did not want global settings to mess with my settings for individual services that I set inside `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.

As you can see I used no `-o` options for the service `smtp` while I used a lot `-o` options for service `smtps`. What confuses me most is that in the official documentation `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I can find a lot of almost duplicated options like:

- [`smtp_tls_protocols`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_protocols)
- [`smtpd_tls_protocols`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_protocols)

According to the cited text I should use:

- the ones starting with `smtp_` for *"outgoing mail"*
- the ones starting with `smtpd_` for *"incomming mail"*.

If my philosophy is correct, then my current setup should work. It partialy does because I can achieve a TLS 1.3 handshake using `openssl` command on a different computer like this:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> openssl s_client -connect pis.eu:465 -tls1_3

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = tek-eu
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = tekpi-eu
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = tek-eu
   i:CN = tek-eu
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

  < REMOVED FOR CLARITY >

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = tek-eu

issuer=CN = tek-eu

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1286 bytes and written 313 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 45F832A32F5F27CEAA41B271F28545ECA98DC1AC61F51A484123DD28B2535C30
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 3175AD1641D8D77511FD5C76508D339D01F5D1CE02DBF90F33FEBD334A7E76FD44B52808A846C281616469143977B6F1
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:

    < REMOVED FOR CLARITY >

    Start Time: 1607602078
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
220 mail.pis.eu -------> "HELLO!"
```

Above I used a parameter `-tls1_3` that should work because my configuration parameter `-o smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1` should forbid any handshake other thanTLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. But if change parameter `-tls1_3` to `-tls1` to try TLS 1 handshake it suceeds!?

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> openssl s_client -connect pis.eu:465 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = tek-eu
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = tek-eu
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = tek-eu
   i:CN = tek-eu
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

  < REMOVED FOR CLARITY >

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = tek-eu

issuer=CN = tek-eu

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: MD5-SHA1
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1385 bytes and written 227 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: C1E39786A475DA48ED222EAB5247CCE57D49875AE9A442A73027FBE1F9BB7C4D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 5900F37B79A7949871008A827904F2BA907F42EE8BBC73328CD49DF7E37AF2687C06B316922D7D76DDC36FA1DF912E7A
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:

    < REMOVED FOR CLARITY >
    
    Start Time: 1607602884
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
220 mail.pis.eu -------> "HELLO!"
```

How come that this suceed? What am I doing wrong? Curently my setup only has `-o smtpd_` options. Should I also use `-o smtp_` options? Where should I put these?

As you see I am confused...

Comment: I solved this. The problem was that option `smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1` was only for *"oportunistic TLS"* which is applicable only to ports `25` and `587`. But there is a similar option ` `smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1` that is for "mandatory TLS" which is applicable to port `465` and this is the one that I want. Well in fact now I have both because I want to support only TLS 1.2 & TLS 1.3.

Comment: A much shorter way to ask this: *"Why does my `smtpd_tls_protocols` configuration not affect on my TLS-wrapped service?"* - the answer would mostly be the first sentence of each the 2 relevant sections in `man postconf(5)`.